# How to close (ctools) modal node/add form after submit?

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I wrote this module that print the node/add form for a content type (article) in a ctools modal window. It works and the new node is saved, but the modal window remains opened after submitting the form.

I would like to automatically close the modal window after saving the node, end and optionally redirect drupal to the new node. Any hint?

```
      <?php


    function modaltest_menu()
    {
    $items['modaltest']            = array(
        'title' => 'Modaltest Page',
        'page callback' => 'modaltest_page',
        'access arguments' => TRUE
    );
    $items['modaltest/%ctools_js'] = array(
        'title' => 'Modaltest page 2',
        'page callback' => 'modaltest_page_modal',
        'page arguments' => array(
            1
        ),
        'access arguments' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
}


      function modaltest_page_modal($js = NULL)
    {
      $nojs_message = t('Hello World');
    if (!$js) {
        return $nojs_message;
    }
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('article');
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $output   = array();
    $output[] = ctools_modal_command_display(t('My modal test'), $form);
    print ajax_render($output);
    exit();
}


    function modaltest_page()
    {
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_modal_add_js();
    return ctools_modal_text_button(t('Popup link'), 'modaltest/nojs',      t('test popup'), 'ctools-modal-test-style');
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of closing the modal if you're redirecting immediately afterwards?

Comment: Indeed you are right, if redirect to a different page, closing the modal window is not needed. So my question comes down to how close the modal window just after submitting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ctools_modal_command_dismiss()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!modal.inc/function/ctools_modal_command_dismiss/7) will close the modal.

You can find more information on that command and ctools modals in general by installing the [Advanced Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module and visiting `/help/ctools/modal`.